# Excel pivot table with ranking

Tags: excel, ms-office, pivot-table, vba

I'm in the processing of creating a report for the company I work at that has a rather complicated survey export file that needs to have the data extracted in meaningful ways.

The table headers are as follow https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Et9Pg6k9CJA3HTO0aHcnSnOWVU05bmHYUsPS0wB2Nr8/edit?usp=sharing

It has respondents listing there top 3 most important options and the rest are left blank.

If anyone can help me figure out a way to potentially summarize this in a pivot table that would be great.

Comment: This stirred an ancient memory where I had used multiple response in SPSS. Try googling it - it might possibly help - but I know you then have to work out how to do a similar thing in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You're data is in a crosstab. Pivot's don't like that kind of layout. You need to unpivot your data.

If you've got the PowerQuery add-in installed (or have Excel 2016 or Excel/Office 365 subscription) then you can use PowerQuery to do this. Google "PowerQuery" and "Unpivot" and you'll turn up a whole heap of videos.

Otherwise you can use VBA such as my Unpivot routine I've previously blogged about at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/

Answer (score 0):

As always it depends what questions you want to ask in your analysis. Here are two suggestions.

**What are the commonest first/second/third choices?**

This assumes that the ranking is important, i.e. the first choice is ranked significantly higher than the second choice, so you want to analyse them separately.

You could add three extra columns to your data using this formula to convert the first choice to a single variable with 11 categories

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(COLUMNS($A:A),$A3:$K3,0),"")
```

in L3 and likewise with the second and third choices in M3 and N3.

in the event that a respondent (row) has less than three choices, it will give a blank for the second and/or third choice.

**What are the commonest choices regardless of ranking?**

This assumes that the ranking isn't so important - you just want to know which columns have been picked overall.

```
=INDEX($L$3:$N$10,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/3)+1,MOD(INT(ROWS($1:1)-1),3)+1)
```

In N3. This would have to pulled down for 3N rows, where N is the number of rows in the original dataset.

[image]

Then it would be a simple case of setting up pivot tables or charts for the four new variables.